# Tab select event not working for jQuery 1.8.3

Tags: jquery, select, tabs

I am trying to get the tab select event fired for quite some time for the jQuery 1.8.3 but not sure why it can't. I fiddled with jsfiddle and have working mockups but when I apply those changes to my jquery file - it doesn't work.

The only way remains is to upgrade the version to newest but I would prefer not to introduce this change for now because we are in final stage of deployment to Prod.!

[image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]

Comment: What version of jquery UI are you using? the latest doesn't have a select event.

Comment: I tried to update the picture again. jQuery-ui.js and jQuery-1.8.3.js

Comment: You are using jQuery UI 1.10, there is no select event. try using the activate event instead.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502156/jquery-ui-tabs-get-the-id-of-the-tab-div-being-activated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"activate" worked for me! As **Kevin B** mentioned for JQueryUI- 1.10 select event is no more!

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {

        alert("hi");
    } 
});
```